# IPv6 encapsuling on Azure ILPIP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Use of IPv6 tunnels (like tunnelbroker.net) is possible on Azure VM, via ILPIP (Instance Level Public IP)?

I tried to use it, but I don't get replies for ping packets to IPv6 gateway.

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 100.90.204.79, Dst: 216.66.84.46
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 124
    Identification: 0x33d7 (13271)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 255
    Protocol: IPv6 (41)
    Header checksum: 0xea66 [validation disabled]
        [Good: False]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 100.90.204.79
    Destination: 216.66.84.46
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Internet Protocol Version 6, Src: 2001:470:1f14:105a::2, Dst: 2001:470:1f14:105a::1
    0110 .... = Version: 6
    .... 0000 0000 .... .... .... .... .... = Traffic class: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        .... 0000 00.. .... .... .... .... .... = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... .... ..00 .... .... .... .... .... = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    .... .... .... 1001 0111 0111 0110 1010 = Flowlabel: 0x0009776a
    Payload length: 64
    Next header: ICMPv6 (58)
    Hop limit: 64
    Source: 2001:470:1f14:105a::2
    Destination: 2001:470:1f14:105a::1
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Internet Control Message Protocol v6
    Type: Echo (ping) request (128)
    Code: 0
    Checksum: 0xd3f8 [correct]
    Identifier: 0x5016
    Sequence: 1
    [No response seen]
        [Expert Info (Warn/Sequence): No response seen to ICMPv6 request in frame 212]
            [No response seen to ICMPv6 request in frame 212]
            [Severity level: Warn]
            [Group: Sequence]
    Data (56 bytes)
        Data: 8bb5ed56000000006ed40d00000000001011121314151617...
        [Length: 56]
```

I suspect that Azure is rejecting IPv4 protocol 41, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The following is [documented](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/faq/):

> Microsoft has played a leading role in helping customers to smoothly transition from IPv4 to IPv6 for the past several years. To date, Microsoft has built IPv6 support into many of its products and solutions like Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2. Microsoft is committed to expanding the worldwide capabilities of the Internet through IPv6 and enabling a variety of valuable and exciting scenarios, including peer-to-peer and mobile applications. The foundational work to enable IPv6 in the Azure environment is well underway. However, we are unable to share a date when IPv6 support will be generally available at this time.

Comment: This says about general IPv6 support, not about 6in4 which encapsulates v6 into v4 packets. (but with protocol 41 in header, which i suspect azure drop on firewall (but i thought that ILPIP are directly connected to VM, without any firewalls))